# TimeoutException object is not callable in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In running the below code, I get TimeoutException object is not callable.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
   WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[@class='ui-state-default']"))).click()

except exceptions.TimeoutException as te:

   Do something
```

The complete error message is below:

```
open_date_found = WebDriverWait(driver, 2, ).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[@class='ui-state-default']"))).click()
TypeError: 'TimeoutException' object is not callable
python-BaseException
```

The error message comes in running the second line of the code, it does not even catch the exception.

**Update**:
I changed the code as below to ignore the exception. However, I get TimeoutException error. Selenium does not ignore it!

```
    open_date_found = WebDriverWait(driver, 2, .5, TimeoutException).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[@class='ui-state-default']"))).click()
```

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x003037D3]
    (No symbol) [0x00298B81]
    (No symbol) [0x0019B36D]
    (No symbol) [0x001CD382]
    (No symbol) [0x001CD4BB]
    (No symbol) [0x00203302]
    (No symbol) [0x001EB464]
    (No symbol) [0x00201215]
    (No symbol) [0x001EB216]
    (No symbol) [0x001C0D97]
    (No symbol) [0x001C253D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0057ABF2+2510930]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005A8EC1+2700065]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005AC86C+2714828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003B3480+645344]
    (No symbol) [0x002A0FD2]
    (No symbol) [0x002A6C68]
    (No symbol) [0x002A6D4B]
    (No symbol) [0x002B0D6B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76777D69+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7790BB9B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x7790BB1F+191]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code that you have shared seems to be fine, since the line can possibly throw an exception and you've handled it.
From the error itself, it seems that you are trying to do something equivalent to `te()` and it's that line that's causing the conflict. Can you share the error handling code?
**Edit**:
Try:

```
e = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[@class='ui-state-default']")))
e.click()
```

Comment: I even removed the te. Nothing changed. I have added more information to the main post. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much, Rashhocket, for your help! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch the raw expection. As you have used *WebDriverWait* catch the *`TimeoutException`* only:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//a[@class='ui-state-default']"))).click()
    
except TimeoutException:
    # Do something
```

Comment: Tried it and still get the same error! Thank you.